# Match Phone Number using Regex 5X000Y000

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the pattern 5X000Y000 of 9 digit number.

**What I have tried**

I have written the below regex

```
B_5 = 530004000

B_5_pattern = re.sub(r'^5(\d(000))(\d(000))', "Bronze", str(B_5))

print(B_5_pattern)
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to update my regex to add a condition that X000 can not be the same as Y000. `(X!=Y)`.

So the regex will match `530004000` but will not match `530003000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```py
B_5 = "530004000"
if re.search(r'^5(\d)0{3}(?!\1)\d0{3}$', B_5):
    print("MATCH")
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^5(\d)0{3}(?!\1)\d0{3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHoUDB/2)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `5`: Match digit `5`
- `(\d)`: Match a digit and capture in group #1
- `0{3}`: Match 3 zeroes
- `(?!\1)`: Make sure next digit is not same as that of captured group #1
- `\d`: Match a digit
- `0{3}`: Match 3 zeroes
- `$`: End